# Windows Installer log shows registry entry added, but doesn't exist in registry after install

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2012

The installer I'm working on has a component that installs registry elements into the 64bit HKLM hive, and installs similar keys into the 32bit hive (under Wow6432Node). On install the log shows the 64bit:

```
MSI (s) (40:30) [13:29:49:879]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=SOFTWARE\Company\Product,,BinaryType=1,)
MSI (s) (40:30) [13:29:49:879]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=MyValueName,Value=MyValue,)
WriteRegistryValues: Key: \SOFTWARE\Company\Product, Name: MyValueName, Value: MyValue
```

then later the 32bit..

```
MSI (s) (40:30) [13:29:49:910]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Company\Product,,BinaryType=1,)
MSI (s) (40:30) [13:29:49:910]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=MyValueName,Value=MyValue,)
WriteRegistryValues: Key: \SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Company\Product, Name: MyValueName, Value: MyValue
```

However, when I go look in the registry at `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Company\Product`, the value isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer with the data provided. Perhaps the installer aborted and rollback.  Perhaps another component duplicated the registry data and changed it later.  Perhaps a custom action fired and reset the value.  Or even another MSI that was part of a bootstrapper stepped on it.

I'd need to spend time on a VM testing your installer to know exactly what happened.   There is no systemic problem in WriteRegistryValues that I'm aware of.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added: the installer completed successfully. No custom actions that touch this value, or other MSI files that run and edit that location.

Comment: The only other information is that I changed the component from a 32bit component (with only the default SOFTWARE\Company\Product) to a 64bit component with both 64bit and 32bit paths inside of it. The issue shows up when upgrading from a previous build to the latest.

Comment: Are you doing major upgrades or minor upgrades? If major, where is RemoveExistingProducts scheduled?

Comment: Major - we change the product code every build. RemoveExistingProducts is scheduled immediately after InstallValidate.

Answer (score 0):

**"...the issue shows up when upgrading from a previous build to the latest"**

Since this is the case I would:

- Split the 32 and 64 bit sections to use two different components. It that is possible.
- Set the key path of the new component to the location that was NOT set by the
  previous install. In other words: ensure both components have key paths and that they are different.
- Enable "re-evaluate component condition" (transitive component) for both components. This re-evaluates installed component conditions during reinstall. In other words determines whether they are to be installed, reinstalled or removed on the system.

If the **component key path** for the previous install exists on reinstall, the new registry key that you have effectively added by enabling 64 bits will not be installed since a component is only installed as a whole or not at all.